# How to make an array of dates with the data that I have

Tags: python, arrays

Is there any simple python code to make the arrays from table above to the below?

Can't quite find any way doing so

Image as below

[Table #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmij.png)

| Name | Year | Savings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | 2012 | 100 |
| Matt | 2013 | 120 |
| Matt | 2014 | 130 |
| Jane | 2013 | 120 |
| Jane | 2014 | 130 |

to below

Table #2

| Name | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | 100 | 120 | 130 |
| Jane | 0 | 120 | 130 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Year']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
Year    2012   2013   2014
Name                      
Jane     0.0  120.0  130.0
Matt   100.0  120.0  130.0
```